CNN not converging as expected in simple object detection problem
I am just beginning to learn Tensorflow for fun, and am having a ton of difficulty training my CNN in a simple object detection task. In particular, I'm trying to train a network to play "Where's Waldo?" using Tensorflow in Python. I have generated training data similar to as in this article, whereby I paste an image of Waldo onto the background of a 500x500 pixel image in a random location, and with a random size (between 23 and 43 pixels in width). For now, I am working with a purely gray background image just to test the network and training out, though I have tried with other images and they failed in much the same way. Here is a sample image, for reference.

For training, the x_batch includes arrays representing images of the above form, but without the green box. The y_batch includes 3 floats representing the row, column, and size of the box around Waldo. Both the x_batch and y_batch are normalized so that all values are between 0 and 1. Here is the network architecture that I am using:
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(500,500,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding="same", kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="valid", kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,2), padding="valid", kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid'))

To train the network, I am using the Adam optimizer with a custom learning rate scheduler, and the categorical cross entropy loss function (I have also tried with mse):
def lr_schedule(epoch, lr):
    if (epoch + 1) % 5 == 0: 
        lr *= 0.4
    return max(lr, 3e-7)
            
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(gen.generate_data(), epochs=10, steps_per_epoch = 50, callbacks = [VisCallback(),
                                                                                    tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)])

The function gen.generate_data() creates the batches as described above (I am using a batch size of 16, but have also tried with 32), and the VisCallback() function just has the network create an image with a red box describing its prediction after every epoch.
When running the code, 99% of the time, one of two things happens:

The network quickly converges, and predicts that Waldo is at the center of the image, regardless of where he actually is.
The network quickly diverges to predicting that Waldo is in one of the corners of the image, regardless of where he actually is (this happens almost every time when using the categorial_crossentropy loss function).

On one irregular occasion, the network actually did begin to correctly guess where Waldo was (within about 10% accuracy, where it remained indefinitely), but the behavior has not been reproducible as yet. I am at somewhat of a loss about how to proceed from here. The fact that is converges to the center makes some sense, as it is the average position of Waldo over a large sample of randomly distributed data. But I have not heard of this issue in other object detection problem this post, which had additional issues in the code, such as using softmax for the output. Can anyone provide some guidance or recommendations for how to combat these kinds of issues?

I guess it's related to the issue of learning rate. And the generalization of the loss function diverging or converging is not a simple issue. But as for recommendation:

In most of the cases, learning rates and optimization function mostly matters. First try simple optimization function like SGD, and try another one and so on. Adam needs more understanding than only just SGD method.
So by given number 1, assuming that you found the learning rate and optimization function you want, than check out for the composition of the model layers. Of course, model layers must be considered whether it is valid on the first place, but in this recommendation I mean the composition of the layers. If there are too many layers or less nodes, overall accuracy falls down.
And by so 1 and 2, if you get clear with learning rate and optimization function, then you can try other loss functions. It is important that there is a gap between loss function for simple regression and classification. For example, if you use regression loss function in classification, whether the loss diverges or converges or not, you are about to get non-adequate accuracy or result.

These are the simple recommendations, although. But clearly it is important in any case of deep learning.
